# Xpath issues selecting <spans> nested in <td>

Tags: html, xml, xpath, xhtml, xquery

I'm trying to extract text from a lot of XHTML documents with a program that uses Xpath queries to map the text into a structured table. the XHTML document looks like this

```
<td class="td-3 c12" valign="top">
 <p class="pa-4">
  <span class="ca-5">text I would like to select </span>
 </p>
</td>
<td class="td-3 c13" valign="top">
 <p class="pa-2">
  <span class="ca-0">some more text I want to select </span>
 </p>
 <p class="pa-2">
  <span class="ca-0">
 <br>
 </br>
  </span>
 </p>
 <p class="pa-2">
 <span class="ca-5">text and values I don't want to select.</span>
 </p>
 <p class="pa-2">
  <span class="ca-5"> also text and values I don't want to </span>
 </p>
</td>
```

I'm able to select the the spans by their class and retrieve the text/values, however they're not unique enough and I need to filter by table classes. for example only the text from **span class ca-0** that is a child of **td class td-3 c13**

which would be `<span class="ca-0">some more text I want to select </span>`

I've tried all these combinations

`//xhtml:td[@class="td-3 c13"]/xhtml:span[@class = "ca-0"]`

`//xhtml:span[@class = "ca-0"] //ancestor::xhtml:td[@class= "td-3 c13"]`

`//xhtml:td[@class="td-3 c6"]//xhtml:span[@class = "ca-0"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is 
     `//td[(@class ="td-3") and (@class = "c13)]/p/span`

for some reason it sees the

```
<td class="td-3 c13">
```

as separate classes e.g.

```
<td class = "td-3" and class = "c13"
```

so you need to treat them as such

Thanks to @E.Wiest and @JackFleeting for validating and pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how much your sample xml reflects your actual xml, but strictly based on your sample xml (AND disregarding possible namespaces issues you will probably face), the following xpath expression:

```
//td[contains(@class,"td-3")]/p[1]/span/text()
```

selects

```
text I would like to select
some more text I want to select
```

Comment: Tried a few variants of this, this was the closest `//xhtml:td[contains(@class,"td-3 c13")]/xhtm:p[1]/xhtm:span/text()` and i had this error `XDMP-TOOFEWARGS: (err:XPST0017) fn:contains(@class = "td-3 c13") -- Too few args, expected 2 but got 1`     
it seems to be a soon as i try to use the table class e.g. class = "td-3 c13" it doesn't work

Comment: @Lobstersack I have no idea why Marklogic (which is what I think you're using) is giving you that error message. The `contains()` function you have`contains(@class,"td-3 c13")` is definitely correct. The error message has an invalid `contains` format: `contains(@class = "td-3 c13")` (note the `=` instead of `,`).  I don't have ML installed so can't troubleshoot it. Maybe it's a bug?

Comment: good guess! it is mark logic. Yeah maybe a bug with MarkLogic Data Hub or namespace issue like you said. I tried both ways of (@class = "td-3 c13") and (@class, "td-3 c13") and get two different errors. I can hit every other span class, however still cant narrow it down to table classes.

Comment: @Lobstersack What's the error you get when you use `(@class, "td-3 c13")`?

Comment: its goes through without failing but provides nothing back. it only seems todo this with the td classes. thanks for all your help so far.

Comment: do i have to do anything with <valign="top">?

Comment: ok starting to pick up the problem, I can query //td[@class="td-3"] and get all the td-3 tables, but as soon add the c13 e.g. //td[@class="td-3 c13"] it comes back empty

Answer (score 0):

According to the [doc](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/xquery/xpath), and to support namespaces, you should write something like this (fn:...) :

```
//*:td[fn:contains(@class,"td-3")]/*:p[1]/*:span
```

Or with a binding namespace :

```
node.xpath("//xhtml:td[fn:contains(@class,'td-3')]/xhtml:p[1]/xhtml:span", {"xhtml":"http://example.com/ns"})
```

This expression should work too (select the first span of the first p of each td element) :

```
//*:td/*:p[1]/*:span[1]
```

Side notes :

Your XPath expressions could be fixed. Span is not a child but a descendant, so we use `//`. We use `()` to keep the first result only.

```
(//xhtml:td[@class="td-3 c13"]//xhtml:span[@class = "ca-0"])[1]
(//xhtml:td[@class="td-3 c6"]//xhtml:span[@class = "ca-0"])[1]
```

Replace `//` with a predicate `[]` :

```
(//xhtml:span[@class = "ca-0"][ancestor::xhtml:td[@class= "td-3 c13"]])[1]
```

Test your XPath with : https://docs.marklogic.com/cts.validIndexPath

Comment: thanks for answering. I'm still having issues pointing this to the td classes. I tried all the examples you showed me with varied results; 1st ' -- arg1 is not of type xs:string'  2nd i couldnt get to run. 3rd worked! however I still need to narrow it down to the td class e.g. //*:td[@class = "td-3 c13"]/*:p[1]/*:span[1] - this is valid, but returns nothing.  for the next two I receive this ` arg1 is not of type xs:string?` are these td classes cursed?? haha. and the last one was valid and produced nothing.

Comment: ok starting to pick up the problem, I can query //td[@class="td-3"] and get all the td-3 tables, but as soon add the c13 e.g. //td[@class="td-3 c13"] it comes back empty

Comment: If it works with `//td[@class="td-3"]` (3 elements returned), it will not work with `//td[@class="td-3 c13"]`. `@class=` implies only one solution and you've found it. You can't be more specific on this td. You need to look elsewhere. `//*:td[@class = "td-3"]/*:p[1]/*:span[1] ` is not enough ? Feel free to post an updated version of your sample data. Which software (+ version) do you use ?